# ATOM feed + Google Analytics Javascript = validation?

Tags: xml, validation, google-analytics, rss, atom-feed

Would it be possible to stick my Google Analytics Javascript slug into my ATOM feed and still have it validate? I don't want to feedburn my feed, but would like the demographic info GA provides.

Answer (score 1):

No it wouldn't because ATOM readers don't run javascript. So the GA snippet won't run.

You have to use other ways to find out how many people really download your atom feeds. And then there's a bigger problem that most people will read your feeds through Google Reader or some kind of web reader. That means people won't be downloading your feed, but the webreader will on server side. So it gets even more complicated. Besides tracking how many people download your feeds you have to use Google Reader API to get the number of subscribers. For that reason feedburner is still your best friend when you want feed analytics.

If you really want to track feed usage and don't want feedburner you could provide ATOM feeds with only a small part of your content and a link to your website to read the whole content. Then you track people on your site analytics.